# Get Date from timestamp in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy, timestamp

As trivial as it may seem, I cannot find a way to transform a Unix timestamp into a Date object in Groovy.

Let me try with `1280512800`, which should become `Fri, 30 Jul 2010 18:00:00 GMT`

My first attempt was

```
new Date(1280512800)
// wrong, becomes Thu Jan 15 20:41:52 CET 1970
```

Then I read that Java timestamps use milliseconds, hence I should use

```
new Date((long)1280512800 * 1000)
// the cast to long is irrelevant in Groovy, in any case I get
// Thu Jan 08 03:09:05 CET 1970
```

What is the right way to convert a timestamp to a Date? What if I want to specify the timezone to work in?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is it's going with Integers, then the multiplication is causing truncation...

Try:

```
new Date( 1280512800L * 1000 )
```

or

```
new Date( ((long)1280512800) * 1000 )
```

Comment: As a quick note this is due to [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5185) with cast precedence in Groovy