# Convert from Unix Timestamp to date in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

I have a date in unix timestamp and I want to convert it to human readable...

```
 def dateUnix = 1486146877214
 Date dateObj =  new Date( ((long)dateUnix) * 1000 )
 def cleanDate = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateObj)
 println "clean date $cleanDate"
```

This gives me..

```
  clean date 49064-02-13
```

where I was expecting "2017-02-03".

What am I doing wrong?

I even casted the timestamp to a long explicitly as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448450).

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403542/groovy-convert-a-timestamp-string-to-epoch-time-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't multiply by 1000 - new Date(long) is in millisecs not microsecs

Answer (score 6):

To convert [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) to Java Date:

```
def timestamp = 1486146877214 // milliseconds
def date = new Date( timestamp ).toString()
assert 'Fri Feb 03 13:34:37 EST 2017' == date.toString() // EN/US date format
```

Create timestamps and/or confirm dates at [TimestampConvert.net](https://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&timestamp=1061056800) or [EpochConverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/), [etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=timestamp+converter).