# convert Epoch time to date timestamp using groovy

Tags: arrays, json, date, groovy, date-formatting

I have JSON like

```
[
   {
     "Name": "ABC", 
     "ID": 1,
     "StartDate": 1444845395112
   }, 
   {
     "Name": "PQR", 
     "ID": 2,
     "StartDate": 1444845395119
  }
]
```

I want to create object array from json array with StartDate like 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' EST timestamp. I also want to add current_timestamp to it with same format.

```
 json.collect { it.Name, it.ID, it.StartDate, current_timestamp}
```

I want array should print like like
[[ABC, 1, 2015/10/14 11:26:35:112 PM, 2022/04/17 03:05:43:236 PM],[…]]

Comment: what is your question/issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from Unix Timestamp to date in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403959/convert-from-unix-timestamp-to-date-in-groovy)?

Comment: @OleV.V. This doesn’t solve my issue. I have updated my question.

Comment: If you want collect to return an array, you have to create one. E.g. add `[]` around the return. `json.collect { [it.Name, it.ID, it.StartDate, current_timestamp] }`.  If that is not the problem at hand, please be explicit about the problem/error you are facing - saves us all the guessing.